# React router conditional

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, router

I have multiple routers i import `Nav` component in `index.js` i need to show `Nav` only for `About` but i don't want to show `Nav` component for `Topics`. I do not want to import the `Nav` component inside `Home` and `About`, since I can have a lot of routers

```
const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Nav />
      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

You can also look at the complete [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-qct7n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a HOC Layout that can take an additional props noNav to hide you nav:

Component Layout:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "../components/Nav/Nav";

const Layout = ({ children, noNav }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {noNav ? null : <Nav />}
    <hr />

    {children}
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./components/About";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Topics from "./components/Topics";
import Layout from "./hoc/Layout";

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={() => (
          <Layout>
            <Home />
          </Layout>
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/about"
        render={() => (
          <Layout>
            <About />
          </Layout>
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/topics"
        render={(props) => (
          <Layout noNav>
            <Topics {...props} />
          </Layout>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-k1ve2?file=/index.js:0-874

Answer (score -1):

you can use windows.location.pathname to identify the correct path then if your path matches exact to "/" then Nav component will be render orelse it doesn't.It can be achieve using terinary operator

```
const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
     {window.location.pathname === "/" ? <Nav /> :""}
      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: I get an error, "windows is not defined".

Comment: I replaced windows with window, but this code does not work

Comment: sry folks its window.location.pathname . but its work for me!!

Comment: Please provide me in this case your sample code in Codesandbox